# How to make the path of an svg inside an img tag clickable?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a logo that I need it to be in SVG, it is inserted in a page like so:

```
<div>
  <img class="footer-logo" src='assets/logo.svg'>
</div>
```

I want the logo to be clickable, and I tried with the below, but the problem is that in doing like so, it makes the full square that contains the svg clickable, I only want the paths of the SVG to be clickable. How can I achieve this? This is what I tried

```
<a href="#" class="svg">
  <object data="img/twitter.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="mailicon">
  </object>
 </a>
```

Comment: Any JS fiddle please !

Comment: images ar not interactive you cannot do what you want with an img tag. If you want just part of an SVG to be clickable, use an object tag and then edit the img/twitter.svg file to wrap the path it contains with an <a> tag.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `<a>` tags to your SVG. Not your HTML.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...>
 <a xlink:href="my_url.html">
    <path d="..."/>
 </a>
</svg>
```

You need to use an `<object>` element to embed your SVG. An `<img>` will not work.

```
<object data="assets/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SVG file is raw, then just use this :

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
<a href="#">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</a>
</svg>
```

or if you have an object, use this

```
<a href="" style="display: block; z-index: 1;">
    <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg" style="z-index: -1; pointer-events: none;" />
</a>
```

the square result in clickable area is based on your svg file shape, not the svg image shape.

Answer (score -4):

> Open that page in Adobe Dreamweaver and choose mapping tool.
>   Select Design mode
>   Create area whichever you want to clickable
>   You will get the coord attribute.